# How to resize image randomly but proportional to the original image? PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm doing this:

```
height = randint(100,1000)
width = randint(100,1000)

image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I run the risk of the image being horizontal, and it turn into a vertical image...

How to resize image randomly but proportional to the original image?

Comment: Resize, in what direction? Increase, decrease, either?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Replace the second line with this:
new width= (newheight/oldheight)* old width 
Not a python coder, but this should mathematically do the trick once you express it in python.

Comment: This ought to do it, although you lose some precision thanks to the truncating nature of Python 2's integer division rules. It would be better to do the division after the multiplication: `new_width = (old_width * new_height) / (old_height)`

Comment: That did not work for me, because my width always gives zero. I did the following: `row, column = image.size <br/> random = randint(1, 100) <br/> width = row / random <br/> height = column / random `

Comment: Perhaps explicit declaration of a float type could prevent a zero width...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomizing the height and width separately, you can just use one randint and multiply that random number by the aspect ratio.

Assume your aspect ratio is 4:3

```
num = randint(100, 1000)
image = image.resize((4*num, 3*num), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

You can also use `image.width` and `image.height` instead of hardcoding the number inside

`image = image.resize((image.width*num, image.height*num), Image.ANTIALIAS)`